# AzureAD - Block Access by EmployeeID

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

Working on blocking users by EmployeeID in AzureAD.

The CSV file has a column EmployeeID setup as:

```
EmployeID
---------

9999
12345
23452
24354
234234
```

Here is what I have so far

```
$TermedUsers = Import-csv "C:\temp\testtermed1.csv"

foreach ($Termed in $TermedUsers){

Set-AzureADUser -ObjectID (Get-AzureADUser | where-object {$_.ExtensionProperty.employeeId -eq $Termed}).EmployeeID -AccountEnabled $false

}
```

The error message I get is:

```
Set-AzureADUser : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'ObjectId' because it is null.
At line:5 char:27
```

I attempted to work off a script I found on Microsoft, which will block via UPN in .txt:

```
Get-Content "C:\My Documents\Accounts.txt" | ForEach { Set-AzureADUSer -ObjectID $_ -AccountEnabled $true }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you,

Comment: I see `EmployeID` (one `e`) in your text file, but `EmployeeID` two `e`s in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the script you provided, we cannot use the property "EmployeeId"   as the ObjectId. They are different properties of a user.

EmployeeId :  The employee identifier assigned to the user by the organization
ObjectId : The unique identifier for the user. Inherited from Directory.

Regarding how to set Azure AD user, please refer to the following script :

1. CSV file

[image]

2. Script

```
Connect-AzureAD

$r = Import-csv E:\test.csv

$r.EmployeeID

foreach($id in $r.EmployeeID ){

 Set-AzureADUser -ObjectId (Get-AzureADUser | where-object {$_.ExtensionProperty.employeeId -eq $id}).ObjectId -AccountEnabled $false
 (Get-AzureADUser | where-object {$_.ExtensionProperty.employeeId -eq $id}) | Select-Object ObjectId , AccountEnabled

}
```

[image]

Update

According to my test, if we directly pass `$Termed` to filter Azure AD user, it is wrong. It is an Object, it is like `@{EmployeeID=666}`. So we need to pass `$Termed.EmployeeID` to filter Azure AD User.
[image]

Comment: awesome, thank you for the quick turnaround and explaining to me where i went wrong. i attempted to run the script, but got the error message 'Set-AzureADUser : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'ObjectId' because it is null.
At line:7 char:28' I verified the EmployeeID existed, which it does. i verified that even after getting the error message...if maybe it did block the user, but it didn't. any idea why i'd get this -objectid error? i have all modules needed for azuread

Comment: i realized that if i change '(Get-AzureADUser | ' to '(Get-AzureADUser -all $true | ', then it'll successfully work. why is that?

Comment: @LarryDavid I have updated my answer. You need to pass ```$Termed.EmployeeID``` to filter Azure AD User.